# Why will the While Loop not end when I ender the correct input?

Tags: python

I have had an issue where I can't get the While loop to terminate.

```
    userinput = ("")

while userinput != ("Search" or "Add"):
  userinput = input("Search or Add?")

  if userinput == "Search":
    Search()
  elif userinput == "Add":
    print("run add request")
  else: print("please choose from the following two options.")
```

Edit: I am sorry the changes have worked. I think after I implemented the changes I had an issue with the Shell running the previous version. Sometimes I have no idea what is happening. Thank you all again.

Edit Edit: Placed the original code back in as I did not take into account that it would confuse anyone looking for their own solution. I am quite new in terms of usage of the site. Thanks again for the help

Comment: It doesn't terminate because you've accounted for all possibilities (if, elif, else) and in all cases you don't tell the loop to terminate (unless you do it explicitly with break in one of the conditional statements, as pointed out in the answers).

Comment: Note that `userinput != ("Search" or "Add"):` is incorrect. It will first do `"Search" or "Add"`, which results in just "Search", and compare that to `userinput`.

Comment: Instead (as just one working option): `while userinput not in ['Search','Add']`

Comment: `!=` does not distribute over `or` like this.

Comment: Tip: use 4 spaces for indentation, not 2. This is the default in Python. Also, just put the `print()` function under the `else` clause, not beside it, for readability.

Comment: @9769953 There is no "default" indentation; rather, 4 spaces is the *recommended* indentation.

Comment: @chepner That gets to arguing semantics: what would you define as a "default"?

Comment: Something that Python does automatically? The amount of indentation used is solely a function of your editor.

Comment: Nothing in the parser looks for 4-space indents specifically; it simply *measures*  how much indentation is used for the first line in an indented block, and requires the same amount be used for all other lines at that level of indentation.

Comment: Please don't edit the code in your question to working code. It makes the answers nonsense and won't help anyone in the future that finds this page in search. Please also consider what I've written about `while True:` (your original code was better, IMO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your `while` test. A couple of things:

1. You can't use `or` like this. `or` needs two full conditions that resolve to `true` or `false`. Here you have one condition `userinput != "Search"` and a string `"Add"`. So it's always going to return `True` since a non-zero value is always `True`.

   As an example:

   ```
   if "Add": print("true")

   >>true
   ```

   Instead:

   ```
   userinput != "Search" or userinput != "Add"
   ```
2. `or` is not correct when testing two negations like `!=`. One of the two conditions will always return `true`. For instance if you input `"Add"` then the condition `userinput != "Search"` will be `True` and your `while` loop will continue since `True or False = True`. So on and so forth. Instead you want an `and`.

   ```
    while userinput != "Search" and userinput != "Add":
   ```

---

As I suggested in my comment though, it's probably just easier to use the `not in` operator on a list:

```
while userinput not in ['Search','Add']:
```

This way as your list grows your test stays nice and small/condense.

---

Also, while this is just my opinion, I applaud your original pre-edit code where you supplied the condition for breaking your `while` loop in the `while` statement instead of doing `while True:`. Having had many years of bug hunting and feature adding and hotfixing, I know every time I see `while True:` I'm going to be hunting through hundreds of lines of codes looking for every `break`. `while True:` and `break` has its time and place (I imagine), but I feel like it should be an exception use-case, not the rule.

Comment: Thank you I admit I didn't want to use a While True: as it doesn't tell me later what it's looking for. But I changed it just to try to get the code to run. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

My solution looks like this:

```
userinput = ""

while userinput != "Exit":
    userinput = input("Search, Add or Exit: ")

    if userinput == "Search":
        print("run search request")
    elif userinput == "Add":
        print("run add request")
    elif userinput != "Exit": 
        print("please choose from Search, Add or Exit.")
```

Notes:

- Variable `userinput` is initialised to `""`. It doesn't need to be a tuple, `("")`
- I introduced an 'Exit' option. We loop until we encounter Exit. No need for `break` or `continue`
- I changed the prompt to a colon and a space, and also show the three options.
- We compare the input to the three options. If nothing valid, print an error message

Answer (score 0):

Using the word `break` will break you out of a `while` loop, like this:

```
while True:
    break
```

Place `break` where you want the while loop to end.

The problem is that once the input is received, and when the input meets the end condition of the `while` loop, and it isn't able to reach the code checking for the condition! Try this:

```
while True:
  userinput = input("Search or Add?")

  if userinput == "Search":
    Search()
    break
  elif userinput == "Add":
    print("run add request")
    break
  else: print("please choose from the following two options.")
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you mark it with a checkmark? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The format was not correct in the while condition statement part, You can try out this...

```
userinput = ("")

while userinput not in ["Search", "Add"]:
  userinput = input("Search or Add?")

  if userinput == "Search":
    Search()
  elif userinput == "Add":
    print("run add request")
  else: print("please choose from the following two options.")
```